# Unable to display child node data in a FirebaseRecyclerView. DatabaseException: Can't convert object to class name

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I need to display a list (Data from Firebase realtime database binded into a `RecyclerView`) which is in root -> History -> UID -> location, date. I'm currently only able to display all the data under History. The problem occurs when I try to filter out the History node to the child node of UID and it gives the following error:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.ModelHistory

Here is my ModelHistory.class:

```
public class ModelHistory {

String location, date;

// Constructor
public ModelHistory() {

}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}
// It shows a warning here that setLocation is never used
public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}
}
```

Here is my RecentHistory.java:

```
public class RecentHistory extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference mRef, uidRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recent_history);

        // Set ActionBar
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("History");

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvHistory);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


        // Set Layout
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        // Send Query to Firebase Db
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        String currentuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

        mRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("History");
        uidRef = mRef.child(currentuser);
        Log.d("TAG", uidRef.toString());

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ModelHistory, ViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ModelHistory, ViewHolder>(
                        ModelHistory.class,
                        R.layout.historyrow,
                        ViewHolder.class,
                        mRef
                        //uidRef  //  Error when I replace this with mRef
                ) {
                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, ModelHistory model, int position) {
                        viewHolder.setHistoryDirectory(getApplicationContext(), model.getLocation(), model.getDate());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                        ViewHolder viewHolder = super.onCreateViewHolder(parent, viewType);
                        return viewHolder;
                    }
                };
        // Set adapter to recycler view
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    }
}
```

Please let me know if the xml is needed, I will edit the post it.

Comment: Please add the structure of your database as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot.

Comment: Here is the link - https://imgur.com/8KyDRoX 

When I use mRef in the above code it shows both the data properly, but I need to filter it to down to the current logged in user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.ModelHistory

Because this is the correct behaviour when you are passing the `uidRef` to the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` constructor.

> I'm currently only able to display all the data under History.

This is happening because your adapter is defined as `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ModelHistory, ViewHolder>`, which means that it should load all the objects of type `ModelHistory` that it finds under your `mRef` reference, which in fact is correct. All the object that exist under that reference are of type `ModelHistory`.

> The problem occurs when I try to filter out the History node to the child node of UID

You cannot simply change the reference and expect the results to be filtered in that way because your adapter is still of type `ModelHistory` and not of type String. So when using the `uidRef` reference, it means that you are trying to load all objects of type `ModelHistory` beneath that reference, which obviously do **not** exits. Under `root -> History -> UID` exist only properties of type String (`location and date`) and that's why you get that error.

If you want to filter that data, you should create a Query that might look like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference hisotryRef = rootRef.child("History");
Query query = hisotryRef.orderByChild("location").equalTo("Test");
```

And the result in your `RecyclerView` will only one item, which is in this case the last one, the one with the location property that holds `Test`.

Beside that, you are using an old version of the [Firebase-UI Library](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android). I recommend you update to the latest version.

Comment: What is the correct practice to query the data under a UID of an already logged in user?

Comment: If you want to get the (history) data that correspond only to a specific user, the simplest solution I can think of is to store under each history object, the `uid` of the user. In this way you can use this query `hisotryRef.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());` In this way you can get all the history of the logged in user, right?

Comment: Yep, did just that after tinkering around. Cheers for the help!